# Beginner question: returning number value from string

Tags: javascript

If I give a value to firstParam as 'Ten' or '10' is there some way I can make the program return a number value to the function?

```
const sum = (firstParam, secondParam) => {
  if (firstParam === Number(firstParam) && secondParam === Number(secondParam))
    return (firstParam - secondParam)
  else
    return ('Invalid argument(s)')
}

console.log(sum(1,1))
```

EDIT

I have tried many different ways changing the firstParam to Number.firstParam, when i get close i miss out on the correct return statements

```
const sum = (firstParam, secondParam) =>{
firstParam = Number.firstParam
if (firstParam === Number(firstParam) && secondParam === Number(secondParam) )
return (firstParam - secondParam); 
else 
return ('Invalid argument(s)')
}
console.log(sum(1,1))
```

Comment: If it's `'10'` then `Number(firstParam)` will work. To parse a worded number requires a lot more work.

Comment: I've tried using Number() I cannot get it to work to give me the correct response on different inputs like (1,2) and (1, "some string") I want it to return the else statement for a input that is a string that is not valid. When i try the number() tip it wont work correct

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a number in form of string. for example '10'.

You can parse it into `Number` and then return the `sum` as shown below.

Example when both arguments are `correct`.

```js
const sum = (firstParam, secondParam) =>{
  let sum = Number(firstParam)+Number(secondParam);
  return Number(sum)?sum:"Invalid argument(s)";
}

console.log(sum('10','1'))
```

Example when anyone of the argument is `incorrect`.

```js
const sum = (firstParam, secondParam) =>{
  let sum = Number(firstParam)+Number(secondParam);
  return Number(sum)?sum:"Invalid argument(s)";
}

console.log(sum('ten','1'))
```

Comment: I've tried this. I cannot get this to work when i use the given if else statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the type of the arguments before trying to convert them to a number:

```js
const sum = (firstParam, secondParam) => {
  // If both are numbers everything is ok
  if (typeof firstParam === 'number' && typeof secondParam ===         'number' ) {
    return (firstParam - secondParam);
  }
 
 
  // If are stingified numebrs we convert them
  const firstParamInNumber = parseFloat(firstParam)
  const secondParamInNumber = parseFloat(secondParam)
  
  return isNaN(firstParamInNumber) || isNaN(secondParamInNumber) ? 'Invalid argument(s)' : firstParamInNumber - secondParamInNumber
}

console.log(sum(1,'1'))
console.log(sum(1,1))
console.log(sum(1,'wrong param'))
```